# How to do one hot encoding in tft using hardcoded values

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I want to apply one hot encoding to my categorical features. I see how one can use `tf.one_hot` to do that but `one_hot` accepts indices so I'd need to map the tokens to indices. But all of the examples I've found are computing the vocab over the entire dataset. I don't want to do that as I have hard-coded dict of possible values. Something like:

```py
CATEG = {
    'feature1': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    'feature2': ['foo', 'bar']
}
```

I just need the `proprocessing_fn` to simply map the tokens to an index then run it through `tf.one_hot`. How can I do that?

---

For example, [`tft.apply_vocabulary`](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/transform/api_docs/python/tft/apply_vocabulary) sounds like what I need but then I see that it takes a `deferred_vocab_filename_tensor` of type `common_types.TemporaryAnalyzerOutputType`? The description says:

> The deferred vocab filename tensor as returned by tft.vocabulary, as long as the frequencies were not stored.

And I see that [`tft.vocabulary`](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/transform/api_docs/python/tft/vocabulary) is again *computing* the vocab:

> Computes The unique values taken by x, which can be a Tensor or CompositeTensor of any size. The unique values will be aggregated over all dimensions of x and all instances.

Why doesn't something simple like this exist?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option is probably to use `tf.equal` as follows

```py
import tensorflow as tf
CATEG = {
    'feature1': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    'feature2': ['foo', 'bar']
}
tokens = tf.constant(CATEG['feature2'])
inputs = tf.constant(["foo", "foo", "bar", "none"])
onehot = tf.cast(tf.expand_dims(tokens, 1) == tf.expand_dims(inputs, 0), dtype=tf.float32)
print(onehot)
# [[1., 1., 0., 0.],
#  [0., 0., 1., 0.]]
```

Add batch dims if needed.